# SQL Server ogr2ogr batch unable to access ogr_MSSQLSpatial.dll

Tags: sql-server, ogr2ogr

I have an ogr2ogr batch file that reprojects SQL data into a new SQL Server table.

It works fine when I run the bat file manually but it fails if I run the bat file via a SQL Server stored procedure. I have given the `gdal` folders SQL Service permissions and `xp_CommandShell` is also enabled. I'm using

```
EXECUTE xp_CMDShell 'blah'
```

in the T-SQL script.

For some reason the `ogr_MSSQLSpatial.dll` causes it to fail.

> ERROR 1: Can't load requested DLL: Z:\BroadSpectrumSQLTreeExtract\ogr2ogr\gdalplugins\ogr_MSSQLSpatial.dll

If I remove this dll the script runs via SQL but it means I need to add extra commands that the dll must take care of, such as setting source coordinate system. I haven't managed to get it working 100%. The furthest I got to was producing the reprojected table but the  geometry field is empty.

The DLL does contain SQL commands to the system tables. Could this be a SQL Server security issue stopping it from working?

Comment: Any takers? I also notice when running this script in cmd line on the server with my login the error says it can't find Z:\BroadSpectrumSQLTreeExtract\ogr2ogr\gdalplugins\ogr_MSSQLSpatial.dll. It runs fine on my machine.

Comment: Have you checked if all the DLL dependencies are ok?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I again had this problem with another ogr2ogr bat while executing with SQL. If I put the bat in the same folder as the dll's it works fine.